# How do I interpolate a 2D gridded point cloud to a continuous area?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, point-clouds

I have a 2 dimensional Numpy NDarray filled with floats between 0 and about 8. This 2 dimensional arrays size is `(1000, 1600)` and there are about 1400 values, (the points in the point cloud), the remaining values are `None`, so matplotlib does not plot these values. You can see the plotted table in the image below. What I'd like to have is, the None-values interpolated with the values next to it to have a gradientlike heatmap. This pointcloud represents the shape of a roof and I want to process this data to an image I can give into a neural network to detect the type of roof.

The code I used for this plot is pretty short,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.clf()
#plotGrid is the numpy.ndarray with shape (1000, 1600) and dtype float
plt.imshow(plotGrid, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Image (click to enlarge and see points):
[image]

Comment: Is `plotGrid.dtype == object`? You might want to consider storing `nan` instead of `None`, to speed things up, as that will allow you to use `.dtype == float`

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `None` values with `0`? My thinking is that the interpolation isn't working because of this.

Comment: I'm not even trying to interpolate these values. I replaced the zeros inside the array by None values, so they don't distort the point cloud. What I am asking for is an efficient way how to interpolate the missing values. Are nan values also skipped by the plotter? Then I will replace the None type by nan values

Answer (score 3):

#### `tricontourf`

You might use a `tricontour` / `tricontourf` plot of the valid values. To this end, you first need to filter out all `nan` values (you should indeed make the invalid values `np.nan` instead of `None`).
Those values, together with their coordinates can be put into `plt.tricontourf()` to obtain a contour plot without the need of manual interpolation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some example data
f = lambda x,y : np.exp((-(x-150)**2-(y-150)**2)/3.e3)
plotGrid = np.zeros((300,300))*np.nan
coo = np.random.randint(5,295, size=(150,2) )
for x,y in coo:
    plotGrid[y,x] = f(x,y)
#plotGrid is now a numpy.ndarray with shape (300,300), mostly np.nan, and dtype float

# filter out nan values and get coordinates.
x,y = np.indices(plotGrid.shape)
x,y,z = x[~np.isnan(plotGrid)], y[~np.isnan(plotGrid)], plotGrid[~np.isnan(plotGrid)]

plt.tricontourf(x,y,z)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### `tripcolor`

Using `tripcolor` is another option then:

```
plt.tripcolor(x,y,z, shading='gouraud')
```

[image]

#### interpolate and `contourf`

You can also interpolate the data on a grid first, using `matplotlib.mlab.griddata`, and then either use a normal `contourf` plot,

```
xi = np.linspace(0, plotGrid.shape[1], plotGrid.shape[1])
yi = np.linspace(0, plotGrid.shape[0], plotGrid.shape[0])
zi = mlab.griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 15)
```

#### interpolate and `imshow`

Or in the same manner use an `imshow` plot,

```
plt.imshow(zi)
```

[image]

Comment: `tripcolor` might be better here, if the contours are too coarse

Comment: So if this answers your question, your may accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) does what you need:

```
import scipy.interpolate

z_all = plotGrid.astype(float)            # convert nones to nan
x_all, y_all = np.indices(plotGrid.shape) # get x and y coordinates

# convert to 1d arrays of coordinates
valid = ~np.isnan(z_all)
x, y, z = x_all[valid], y_all[valid], z_all[valid]

# interpolate
interp = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z)
filled_data = interp(x_all[:,0], y_all[0,:])  # this is kinda gross, but `interp` doesn't
                                              # do normal broadcasting

plt.imshow(filled_data)
```

Comment: This could actually work, but I get an exception because of too many values, so there is an overflow:

'OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate'

Comment: @Baffel: That's pretty unfortunate. Can you give a stack trace? Sounds like a scipy bug, due to an over-dependence on fortran