# bad contour lines plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a hard time with contour plotting. The contour lines are going crazy in my plot, and I'm not sure why. You can see some of the data points in the background.

```
print positive_train_data.shape
#returns (1131,2)

def GaMM():
  GaussMM = GMM(n_components=3)
  GaussMM.fit(positive_train_data)
  X, Y = np.meshgrid(positive_train_data[:, 0], positive_train_data[:, 1])
  XX = np.array([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
  Z = -GaussMM.score(XX)
  Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)
  CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
  CB = plt.colorbar(CS, shrink=0.8, extend='both')
  plt.scatter(positive_train_data[:, 0], positive_train_data[:, 1])

GaMM()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data seems to be completely unordered. This is similar to what happens in the left picture below.

[image]

This is taken from one answer to this question:
[Why does pyplot.contour() require Z to be a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045921/why-does-pyplot-contour-require-z-to-be-a-2d-array)
and the solution would be to use [`tricontour`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tricontour.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-tricontour) instead of `contour` as shown in the right picture.

The other option is to interpolate the data on a 2D grid, e.g. using [`matplotlib.mlab.griddata`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.griddata)

Further suggested reading are:

- [Plotting Isolines/contours in matplotlib from (x, y, z) data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702920/plotting-isolines-contours-in-matplotlib-from-x-y-z-data-set) for options on how to plot data from x,y,z dataset.
- [How do I interpolate a 2D gridded point cloud to a continuous area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806077/how-do-i-interpolate-a-2d-gridded-point-cloud-to-a-continuous-area) for a more detailed answer concerning filled contours.